# How to disable icefaces info logging

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, icefaces, slf4j

i was wondering how to disable icefaces info logging like:

```
INFO: 
ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
ICEpush 2.0.2
Build number: 6
Revision: 24488

Jan 3, 2012 2:47:48 PM org.icefaces.util.EnvConfig init
INFO: ICEfaces Configuration: 
org.icefaces.render.auto: true [default]
org.icefaces.autoid: true [default]
org.icefaces.aria.enabled: true [default]
org.icefaces.blockUIOnSubmit: false [default]
org.icefaces.compressDOM: false [default]
org.icefaces.compressResources: true [default]
org.icefaces.connectionLostRedirectURI: null [default]
org.icefaces.deltaSubmit: false [default]
org.icefaces.lazyPush: true [default]
org.icefaces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI: null [default]
org.icefaces.standardFormSerialization: false [default]
org.icefaces.strictSessionTimeout: false [default]
org.icefaces.windowScopeExpiration = 1000 [default]
org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration: null [default]
org.icefaces.uniqueResourceURLs: true [default]
org.icefaces.lazyWindowScope: true [default]
org.icefaces.disableDefaultErrorPopups: false [default]

Jan 3, 2012 2:47:49 PM org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.DOMRenderKit <clinit>
INFO: 
ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
ICEfaces 2.0.2
Build number: 8
Revision: 24561
```

i tried adding the following to my log4j configuration with no luck:

```
log4j.logger.org.icefaces=FATAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like ICEfaces is using `java.util.logging`. You must either configure `j.u.l` to discard these messages or (better) redirect `j.u.l` to SLF4J using [bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and control the Log4J output.